# Condition for an integer prime to be a Gaussian prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I have a basic question:

> To show that an integer prime $p$ is a Gaussian prime (i.e. a prime in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z[i]$) if and only if the equation $x^2+y^2=p$ has no integer solutions.

My attempt: if there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+b^2=p$ then $(a+ib)(a-ib)=p$ and so $p$ is not a Gaussian prime.

Conversely, if $p$ is not a Gaussian prime then for some non-units $x+iy$ and $a+ib$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$ we have $(x+iy)(a+ib)=p$. Expanding out the LHS we get $$xa-yb=p$$ and $$xb+ya=0$$

Does it follow from this that there is a solution to the above equation? Am I on the right track?

A hint would be welcome.

Comment: Here's a broad hint: when is the product of two complex numbers a real number?  (You should be able to infer this from the last equation you wrote out...)

Comment: I guess when one is a multiple of the complex conjugate of the other. So $x+iy=n(a-ib)$ for some positive integer $n$ which means $n(a^2+b^2)=p$. Since $a+ib$ is not a unit, $a^2+b^2 \neq 1$ and so $a^2+b^2=p$.

Comment: Pete: pretty close!  (But, for instance, consider 2-2i and 3+3i).  An easier alternative approach, actually, is to multiply both sides of $(x+iy)(a+ib)=p$ by their complex conjugates and use unique factorization over the integers...

Comment: OK, many thanks!