# How to prove that 2 is not a Gaussian prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

To prove an algebraic number is not a Gaussian prime, need find factors of it.
Let us assume, $(a + bi)(x +yi) = 2, \exists a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$; so $(ax -by) + i(ay + bx) =2$.

As imaginary part is null in $2$, so $ax - by =2, ay + bx =0$.

Now, how to reach from here, the fact that $a=x=1, b=i, y=-i$.

I read in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216480/condition-for-an-integer-prime-to-be-a-gaussian-prime) in a comment by @StevenStadnicki, that an easier way is to multiply both sides of $(a + bi)(x +yi) = 2$ by the complex conjugates, but is not clear, as my below attempt shows.
$$
\begin{align}
& ax - by =2, ay + bx =0  & \ \\
\implies & axy - by^2 =2y, axy + bx^2 =0 \text{ }{ -(i)} & \ \\
\implies & b = 0
\end{align}
$$

---

By the answer given below, my attempt is stated below:

Two set of values are possible, one in which $(a^2 + b^2) = 4, (x^2 + y^2) = 1$, second in which $(a^2 + b^2) = 2, (x^2 + y^2) = 2$.

Possible combinations for each of the two cases are stated below:

Case (i): $(a^2 + b^2) = 4, (x^2 + y^2) = 1$ 
$\implies  a= \pm 2, b = 0, x = \pm 1, y = 0$, or $a= \pm 2, b = 0, x = 0, y = \pm 1$. 
 But, as $ax -by =2, ay + bx = 0$. 
 But being algebraic number, need have non-zero imaginary part, hence no algebraic factors of $2$.

Case (ii)  $(a^2 + b^2) = 2, (x^2 + y^2) = 2$ 
$\implies$ possible values are : $  a= \pm 1, b = \pm 1, x = \pm 1, y = \pm 1$.

But, as : $ax -by =2, ay + bx = 0$, so the valid combinations are: 
1. $a=1, b=-1, x=1, y=1$; 
2. $a=1, b=1, x=1, y=-1$, 
3. $a=-1, b=1, x=-1, y=-1$. 
Here, combination 3 is  <del>same as 1, so can be ignored</del>  also valid.

So, the solution has values of $a =1,b=1, x = 1, y = -1$.

If there is a redundancy or unnecessary steps, please tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(a+ib)(c+id)=2$.

There is obviously no solution with real integers, so $b$ and $d$ are both nonzero (if only one is zero, the product is complex or 0, so it also fails). Also, since the product is real, their arguments are opposite: they are multiples of a conjugate pair of gaussian integers.

So it's really $k(a+ib)(a-ib)=2$

Hence

$$k(a^2+b^2)=2$$

So $k$ must be positive. And $k,a,b$ are integers. If $k=2$, it fails because then $b=\pm1$ and $a=0$ (remember $b\ne0$), and the factorization if $2i\times -i=2$ or $-2i\times i=2$, and this proves nothing as you have just multiplied $2$ by a [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)).

Hence let $k=1$ and $a^2+b^2=2$, but then $a^2=b^2=1$. But the sign of $a$ is useless, because $(-a+ib)(-a-ib)=(a+ib)(a-ib)$. Hence, you can pick $a=1$, and the solution has to be

$$(1+i)(1-i)=2$$

Which you can check.

Of course, another solution is

$$(-1+i)(-1-i)=2$$

Comment: You have given answer to my edited OP, but if there a program or algorithm, then still better. Also, your second solution makes my 3rd combination (in edited OP) also valid.

Comment: @jitender And this works every time you can write a rational (real) prime as a sum of the squares of two real integers. Just as $$2 = 1^2 + 1^2 = 1^2 - i^2 = (1+i)(1-i)$$ we have for example $$61 = 6^2 + 5^2 = 6^2 - (5i)^2 = (6+5i)(6-5i).$$

Answer (score 5):

If $(a+bi)(x+yi)=2$, $(a-bi)(x-yi)=2$ and therefore $(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=4$. In how many ways can $4$ be written as the product of two integers, each of which is a sum of $2$ squares? Well, $4=4\times1=(2^2+0^2)\times(1^2+0^2)$ and $4=2\times2=(1^2+1^2)\times(1^2+1^2)$. Therefore, there are few possibilities for you to test.

Comment: But, can there be not a more algebraic way to deduce the factors, and if this is the norm, then there must be some good program somewhere too.

Comment: @jitender If I knew a better way, I would have posted it.